# Fluid dynamical analogs to General Relativity - perfect fluids and bulk viscosity

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics

i have problems understanding the following two articles :

https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.3882 - Viscous Spacetime Fluid and Higher Curvature Gravity

https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.3180 - Viscous gravitational aether and the cosmological constant problem

In the articles spacetime with cosmological constant $\Lambda = 0$ is considered to be a perfect fluid. This is clear to me. Then viscosity is introduced, the viscosity is deeply linked to the cosmological constant. This is also clear to me. What i do not understand is why a bulk viscosity is introduced, because defining a bulk viscosity for an **incompressible fluid** is senseless. Do the articles propose a shift from an incompressible, inviscid fluid (perfect fluid) to an compressible and viscid fluid ?
If the fluid is compressible, does this affect the critical speed i.e. the speed of light ? Because the critical speed in a fluid is only constant for an ideal fluid.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.